# OS X Disk Utility shows more data

Tags: macos, disk-utility

On OS X El Capitan Disk Utility shows me that I have 48 GB Movies, but I don't have this films really.

Where can I find these movies that shows Disk Utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Disk Utility and About This Mac use spotlight data to categorize the used space in terms of classes of data:

[image]

You can use Finder to search for items using the same classes:

[image]

Some notes:

- type in the search box the text: **kind:movie** *(as you type look for the hints as the system shows you possible values of kind)*
- choose list view (the four lines icon top left)
- control click and add size so you can then click it and sort by size

You can save this "smart folder" or add a filter like size > whatever limit you want so you can review all large movie files or just all large files.

Comment: Thank you. It works, 
but I cant understand, why some .ts files or js files are marked as movie? and when I deleted some films, why they saved there too ?

Comment: Hop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) and let's see if you need a quick tip or a new question for that specific item... Does that work @Gor ?